# Alternative Query to Implement Minus Query logic

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

we are using the below-mentioned minus query logic to find out the non-existing record between the 2 tables, is there an alternative logic that can be used via SQL to achieve the same this is causing performance issues and running for a very long time.

```
SELECT EMPLID,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,HR_STATUS,EMPL_STATUS
FROM EDWHRSTG.PS_JOB_FULL_S
WHERE EMPLID = '09762931'
MINUS
SELECT EMPLID,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,HR_STATUS,EMPL_STATUS
FROM SUODS.PS_JOB_S
WHERE EMPLID = '09762931'
```

Comment: Can you share what plan is optimizer taking

Comment: Is EMPLID a key?

Comment: In the sample code you posted, you are doing this just for ***one single employee id***. If **that** is taking a very long time, then check to see if your computer is plugged in; **that** query should take a fraction of a second even if a turtle was running it. Are you sure that is **exactly** the query you want help with?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using an OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT EMPLID,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,HR_STATUS,EMPL_STATUS
  FROM EDWHRSTG.PS_JOB_FULL_S a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT EMPLID,EMPL_RCD,EFFDT,HR_STATUS,EMPL_STATUS
                     FROM SUODS.PS_JOB_S
                     WHERE EMPLID = '09762931') b
    ON b.EMPLID = a.EMPL_ID AND
       b.EMPL_RCD = a.EMPL_RCD AND
       b.EFFDT = a.EFFDT AND
       b.HR_STATUS = a.HR_STATUS AND
       b.EMPL_STATUS = a.EMPL_STATUS
  WHERE b.EMPLID IS NULL AND
        b.EMPL_RCD IS NULL AND
        b.EFFDT IS NULL AND
        b.HR_STATUS IS NULL AND
        b.EMPL_STATUS IS NULL
```

However, I doubt this will perform any better. Your best option is to add an index on the five fields in play here (EMPL_ID, EMPL_RCD, EFFDT, HR_STATUS, EMPL_STATUS) to both tables, or in other words

```
CREATE INDEX EDWHRSTG.PS_JOB_FULL_S_1
  ON EDWHRSTG.PS_JOB_FULL_S (EMPL_ID, EMPL_RCD, EFFDT, HR_STATUS, EMPL_STATUS);
```

and

```
CREATE INDEX SUODS.PS_JOB_S_1
  ON SUODS.PS_JOB_S (EMPL_ID, EMPL_RCD, EFFDT, HR_STATUS, EMPL_STATUS);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify where time is being spent, in order to determine root cause if the performance problem; otherwise it’s just a guess.
An Active SQL Monitor report is your diagnostic tool of choice